# Java getting HTML frame

Tags: java, html, frame, htmlunit

I am working on a Java project for this [website](http://civil.poderjudicial.cl/CIVILPORWEB/?). I need to access the HTML code for frame of the webpage, but I cant seem to be able to do it.

```
<html>
<HEAD>

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<META name="GENERATOR" content="IBM WebSphere Studio">
<META http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">

<TITLE>CONSULTA CAUSAS - Versión 1.15.0.0</TITLE>
</HEAD>
  <frameset rows="120,0*" cols="*" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO" border="0">
    <frame src="/CIVILPORWEB/jsp/General/CIV_GRL_HeadAutoconsulta.jsp" name="head" scrolling="NO" noresize marginheight="144" marginwidth="0">  
    <frameset rows="*" cols="174,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO" border="0">
        <frame src="/CIVILPORWEB/jsp/Menu/Aplicacion/CIV_MNU_AtPublico.jsp" name="menu" scrolling="NO" noresize marginwidth="144">
        <frame src="/CIVILPORWEB/jsp/General/CIV_GRL_Body.jsp" name="body">
    </frameset>
  </frameset>
  <noframes>
    <body>
      <p></p>
    </body>
  </noframes>   
</html>
```

Is there any way of accessing it using HtmlUnit? Or maybe another Java module?

Answer (score 0):

This works here with the latest version of HtmlUnit. To get the (X)Html you can use asXml() instead of asText().

```
    String url = "http://civil.poderjudicial.cl/CIVILPORWEB/?";

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52)) {
        // this page has JS errors even in real browsers; ignore them like real browsers do
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
        // System.out.println("----------------");
        // System.out.println(page.asXml());
        // System.out.println("----------------");
        // System.out.println(page.asText());

        final HtmlPage head = (HtmlPage) page.getFrameByName("head").getEnclosedPage();
        System.out.println("- head ---------------");
        System.out.println(head.asText());

        final HtmlPage menu = (HtmlPage) page.getFrameByName("menu").getEnclosedPage();
        System.out.println("- menu ---------------");
        System.out.println(menu.asText());

        final HtmlPage body = (HtmlPage) page.getFrameByName("body").getEnclosedPage();
        System.out.println("- body ---------------");
        System.out.println(body.asText());
    }
```

If you need the real bytes send from the server for every frame you can do something like this

```
    body.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
```

or

```
    body.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
```

Hope that helps.